# Compare column based on row value and keep greatest

Tags: r

As input dataframe

```
dframe <- structure(list(com = structure(1:2, .Label = c("col1", "em"), class = "factor"), 
    stock1 = c(2.6, 2.05), aim = c(1.55, 3.1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

How is it possible to compare the two rows according to the two values in value column for every other column and keep the greatest one and insert zero to the lower one?

Here an example of expected output

```
> data.frame (com = c("col1","em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 0), aim = c(0,3.10))
   com stock1 aim
1 col1    2.6 0.0
2   em    0.0 3.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not insinsts on using a `tibble` but a `data.frame` you could do

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dframe)

cols <- c("stock1", "aim")
dat[, cols][cbind(1:nrow(dat),
                  max.col(-dat[, cols]))] <- 0 
dat
#   com stock1 aim
#1 col1    2.6 0.0
#2   em    0.0 3.1
```

Apparently you cannot use a matrix to extract / replace values from a `tibble`.

Answer (score 2):

Also a base R possibility:

```
cbind(dframe[, 1], dframe[, -1] * apply(dframe[, -1], 1, function(x) x == max(x)))

   com stock1 aim
1 col1    2.6 0.0
2   em    0.0 3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dframe)){
  min=which.min(dframe[i,-1])
  dframe[i,min+1]=0
}
> dframe
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  com   stock1   aim
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 col1     2.6   0  
2 em       0     3.1
```